# Split Pandas column, then join elements with matching element of another split column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with three columns with the following structure:

```
Name                    |   First Last Name    |    Second Last Name
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1/ Name2 / Name3    |   FLN1 / FLN2 / FLN3 |    SLN1 / / SLN3
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1                   |   FLN1               |    SLN1
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1 / Name2           |   FLN1 / FLN2        |     / SLN2
```

And wish to have something as follows:

```
|Full names                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Name 1 FLN1 SLN1, Name 2 FLN 2, Name 3 FLN 3 SLN3  |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Name1 FLN1 SLN1                                    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Name 1 FLN1, Name 2 FLN 2 SLN2                     |
```

Basically I'm trying to split every column by "/" and then join every element of the resulting array with the appropriate element from the next two columns' arrays.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Provide data in text not images.

Comment: Sorry, correction done.

Comment: @GiordanPretelin did my answer address your question?

Comment: @FChm I had to tweak it a bit but it worked within the context of what I needed. Solution resulted in something as follows:

Comment: fn_df = df[Name].str.split('/', expand=True) + " "+df[First Last Name].str.split('/', expand=True) + " "+df[second Last Name].str.split('/', expand=True)

Comment: df['FULL NAME'] = fn_df[[0,1,2,3]].astype(str).replace('nan', '').apply(lambda x: ", ".join(filter(None, x)), axis = 1)

Comment: In order to generate an extra column within original dataframe with a coma separated list of every full name. Thanks a lot! @FChm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about the format of your data...

I would use the pandas built in str [processing methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':['A / B / C', 'F / G'], 'second':['D / / E', 'H / I']})

full_name_df = df['first'].str.split('/', expand=True) + df['second'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

where `full_name_df` looks like:

```
     0     1     2
0   A D    B    C E
1   F H   G I   NaN
```

As you can see you then get a DataFrame with *n* columns (where *n* is the maximum number of names in a given cell) and the same number of rows as your original DataFrame. I also think in some situations having this additional 'full_name' DataFrame is an advantage, although you could always add it as a column of your original DataFrame.